# How to find if an array or list contains a value in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a customer purchase data extension which has customer id, item id (product id).

I have an offer data extension which has a list of item ids.

My requirement is to offer products to a customer on products he has not purchased.

I have a customer purchase list variable which has `p1`, `p2`, `p3` products for a customer id.

I have an offer de which has `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, `p5`. I need to a list which will have `p1`, `p4`, `p5` as an end result.

I need to know how can I check if a value exists in an array list. For example, if p1 is in customer purchase list which `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, `p5`.

Is there a function to find a value in a list?

Comment: Personally i would deal with this task via sql and not ampscript. I would create a new dataextension and would then compare both of the existing ones with joins to get only the elements you specified. In ampScript i would then print out the product-identifiers which would then be in the new created dataextension.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the real structure of both of these tables. Do Screenshots and obfuscate customer data, or just give us an example with test records. What columns do the tables have? Whats a unique key / constraint? Is each purchase a new record? ... i believe we need more infos to cover this

Comment: you talk about arrays and lists - are you referencing the rowset that comes from the LookupRows() function or is this an actual stringified array or delimited list stored in the DE or otherwise gotten? Please clarify your request and provide more information.